# Django admin and wagtail static files not found

Tags: django, wagtail, django-staticfiles

I have a Django site with wagtail and puput integrated into it, as well as whitenoise handling the static files. For some reason, in production, the static files are working for the regular site, but not for the django admin or wagtail admin.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('clubs/', include('clubs.urls', namespace="clubs")),
    path('members/', include('members.urls', namespace="members")),
    path('videos/', include('videos.urls', namespace="videos")),
    path('cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path('blog/', include(wagtail_urls)),
    path('posts/', include(puput_urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

folder structure

```
staticfiles/
    admin/
    wagtailadmin/
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the issue, and it was in my nginx setup. I was using the root directive instead of alias. This meant that it was adding /static to the path, so it was picking up files in the original static folder, but not the static root, which was /staticfiles. So instead of this

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/web/capclub;
}
```

It should have been

```
    location /static/ {
    alias /home/web/capclub/staticfiles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to add the static paths to your urlpatterns when using whitenoise. It's configuration is taken care of by adding [middleware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise).

Also, using `django.views.static.serve()` for this purpose (it looks like that is what you are doing in the example) is [not suitable for production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development). The docs state that

> This helper function works only in debug mode

This may be related to the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok, so you mean just take out the two static() functions added at the end of urls.py, right? I tried that with a collectstatic command and server restart, but no change unfortunately.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant.

Comment: When you say the static files are 'not working', what do you mean exactly? How are you using the static files in django admin, and are you using the {% static template tag to get the path?

Comment: The css / static files are simply 404 / not found